# Flux subscribed through SSE raise a cancel() event

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 + Spring Webflux application in which I am using Thymeleaf Reactive.

I noticed that on my microservices, when I call an endpoint returning a flux of data in SSE mode (text/event-stream), a cancel() occurs on this flux even if it has been processed correctly.

For example, here's a simple controller endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/posts")
public Flux<String> getCommunityPosts() {
    return Flux.just("A", "B", "C").log("POSTS");
}
```

And here's the subscribed flux logs I get when I request it in SSE mode:

```
2018-02-13 17:04:09.841  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.841  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | request(1)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.842  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | onNext(A)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.847  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | request(1)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.847  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | onNext(B)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.848  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | request(1)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.848  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | onNext(C)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.849  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | request(1)
2018-02-13 17:04:09.849  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | onComplete()
2018-02-13 17:04:09.852  INFO 4281 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] POSTS : | cancel()
```

We can notice the cancel event after the onComplete. I don't have this behaviour when I call the same endpoint through a classic GET request. I suspect this cancel event to make the client side event source (javascript) throw a onError event.

Is it a known/wanted behaviour specific to SSE?

**QUESTION UPDATE**

I actually use SSE on some of my streams because I sometimes need my event sources to get JSON data instead of HTML already processed by Thymeleaf. Should I do it in another way?

I based my implementation on the last method of this example: https://github.com/danielfernandez/reactive-matchday/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/danielfernandez/matchday/web/controller/MatchController.java

However, I may have missed providing some information in my previous post. I use Tomcat Server (8.5.23 with M7), and not Netty server. I forced Tomcat use including the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Using your code on a sample project, this seems to cause the issue.

When I run the code on a Netty server, I get the same results as you:

```
2018-02-14 12:30:48.713  INFO 3060 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.ConcatMapImmediate)
2018-02-14 12:30:48.714  INFO 3060 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : request(1)
2018-02-14 12:30:49.717  INFO 3060 --- [     parallel-2] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : onNext(a)
2018-02-14 12:30:49.739  INFO 3060 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : request(31)
2018-02-14 12:30:50.731  INFO 3060 --- [     parallel-3] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : onNext(b)
2018-02-14 12:30:51.733  INFO 3060 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : onNext(c)
2018-02-14 12:30:51.735  INFO 3060 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 : onComplete()
```

When I run the same code on the Tomcat server, I have the cancel issue:

```
2018-02-14 12:33:18.294  INFO 3088 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.ConcatMapImmediate)
2018-02-14 12:33:18.295  INFO 3088 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : request(1)
2018-02-14 12:33:19.295  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : onNext(a)
2018-02-14 12:33:19.297  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : request(1)
2018-02-14 12:33:20.302  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-5] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : onNext(b)
2018-02-14 12:33:20.302  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-5] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : request(1)
2018-02-14 12:33:21.306  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-6] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : onNext(c)
2018-02-14 12:33:21.306  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-6] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : request(1)
2018-02-14 12:33:21.307  INFO 3088 --- [     parallel-6] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : onComplete()
2018-02-14 12:33:21.307  INFO 3088 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.2 : cancel()
```

Could it be a Tomcat issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem (on Tomcat).

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you should use SSE for finite streams.

When I create a Controller method like:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Flux<String> test() {
    return Flux.just("a", "b", "c").delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).log();
}
```

and request it from a browser (Chrome or Firefox) with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var testEventSource = new EventSource("/test");
    testEventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
</script>
```

I get the following logs on the server:

```
| onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
| request(1)
| onNext(a)
| request(31)
| onNext(b)
| onNext(c)
| onComplete()
| onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
| request(1)
| onNext(a)
| request(31)
| onNext(b)
| onNext(c)
| onComplete()
```

As soon as the `Flux` is completed, the connection is closed by the server and the browser reconnects automatically. This will replay the same sequence over and over again.

The only way I get a `cancel()` event on the server is when I close the browser tab during the stream.

Comment: I edited my initial post with new information based on your code, I forgot to mention that I was using Tomcat server and not Netty server. I actually only reproduce the final cancel() event when my code is running on a Tomcat server.